# I cannot say anything definite/definitely about it

Tags: grammar

I cannot say anything 'definite/definitely' about it

which is correct?

I know many people usually use 'definite' in this sentence.
I cannot find sentences used 'definitely' in that situation.

is there any reason we couldn't use 'definitely'?

Answer (score 1):

We use *definite* as we are describing the thing that we might say:

> "It is a black cat" is a definite statement.
>
> "It might a cat or it might not" is not definite.

When you describe a thing, you use an adjective.

It is possible to use an adverb to describe the manner of "say". Compare:

> He said something musical  (He was talking about music)
>   He said something musically (He was talking in a singing voice)

But if you are using "definitely" it is better placed before the verb it modifies. Compare:

> We cannot definitely say anything about it. (we might say something that is not definite)
>   We definitely cannot say anything about it. (we can't say anything at all)

These have very different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

"Definite" and "definitely" are two different things.  The first is an *adjective* used to modify some noun:

> She said we have **definite** plans for this evening, so I should come home right after work.

while the second is an *adverb* used to modify a verb

> She said we were **definitely** going out this evening, so I should come home right after work.

Either of this can work in your example sentence, but it depends what you want to say.

> "I cannot **definitely** say something about it"

= I'm not sure I can say something.  (adverb modifying "say")

> "I cannot say anything **definite** about it

= I could say something, but I would not be certain it was valid. (adjective modifying "anything")

In many cases it's a subtle difference that does not really change the meaning:

> We don't have an opinion on whether the professor's theory is **definitely** valid (as we have yet to verify her calculations).
>
> We have no **definite** opinion on whether the professor's theory is valid (as we have yet to verify her calculations).